# adding a context manager to pathlib.path

Tags: python, python-2.7, path, monkeypatching

I am playing around with pathlib and I wanted to add a context manager to pathlib.Path, similar to what path.py does.
Here it is an example:

```
import pathlib
def __enter__(self):
    self._old_dir = self.cwd()
    os.chdir(self)
    return self

def __exit__(self, *_):
    os.chdir(self._old_dir)


pathlib.Path._old_dir=None
pathlib.Path.__enter__=__enter__
pathlib.Path.__exit__=__exit__



z=pathlib.Path('/home/another/user')
print pathlib.Path.cwd()
#It prints '/home/myuser/name/'
with z:
    print pathlib.Path.z
    #should be printing /home/another/user
```

However, I got:
`AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object attribute '_old_dir' is read-only`

It is related to the use of `__slots__` in the pathlib.Path definition. I am curious now, what should I do to work around this limitation to monkey-patch pathlib to add this "feature"?

NB. I know I could subclass, it is rather a questions of curiosity, if one would ever want to do that, how would he do?

Comment: Why monkey-patch `Path` when you could just add your own subclass with this behaviour?

Comment: Nothing special, I am just curious about the `__slots__` thing and how one would work around that. I ll edit the question to clarify

Comment: I think using `contextlib.contextmanager` might be easy to solve this one. What do you want to achieve with context management? Is it like you mention for path.py to have not to care about storing previous "state" just enter a section at some place do something and when the block is exited all is restored to previous state? But isn't `pathlib` just the "strings" with some magic to adhere with separators etc to the matching underlying platform rules? As there is no "critical" underlying resource,wouldn't it be more elegant to store state in variables explicitly? iversus the pathlib class?

Comment: Try adding a `__dict__` to `pathlib.Path` — `pathlib.Path.__dict__ = {}` — before the others.